# Parse integer to a float picking the value from a input

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript function to control the values that a user enters on the inputs:

What I need is when the user introduces an integer in a certain input that have the `onfocusout` event, this value will be automatically parsed from the function and will send this value to the input and fulfill with the regex condition.

```js
function validateField(el, type) {
  el.classList.remove('has-error')
  var value = el.value
  var result = false

  if (type === 'string')
    result = value + ''
  if (type === 'integer')
    result = /^[0-9]+$/g.test(value)
  if (type === 'float')
    result = /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/g.test(value)

  if (!result)
    el.classList.add('has-error')

  console.log(`validation is: ${result}`)
  return result
}
```

```html
<label>P.V.P :</label>
<input type="number" required onfocusout="validateField(this, 'float')" class="form-control" id="pvp1" name="pvp1">
```

Comment: Why not simply `step="1"`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand where your issue is? What are you having problems with?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the value of the input in case user has entered incorrect type? It's notable, that JS doesn't have integer or float types, it only has [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating point numbers.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My question is how the function can parse this value from the input and send it back to the same input value to fulfill the regex condition. How can i do that?

Comment: You don't use the return value of `validateField` anywhere, it's not usefull to define a return value in that function at all. The task becomes unnecessarlily complex when using inline listeners, replace `onfocusout` attribute with `data-type` attribute (containing the type value), and add the events to the inputs in the script using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), and convert the value of the input to correct type if needed, and set it to `value` property of the target input.

Comment: You can set value of this input by document.getElementById('').value = parsedvalue`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi That's totally unnecessary DOM query, you already have a reference to the element which triggered the event in the event object.

Comment: So let's say I type `1e5` - a totally valid input for a number input (scientific notation for `10000`). What do you want your code to do with it?

Comment: I forgot to mention when a value is sent and it does not match any of the conditions, I call a css class that surrounds the field in red color so that the user knows that it is wrong

Comment: [There is already validation support in HTML](https://jsbin.com/qucugodeca/1/edit?html,css,output). I'm not really sure why you want to create your own.

Comment: It is useless to set the input value to the value, which matches your test, because this value is there already. It might make sense to erase the value in case of a test failure.

Comment: Have you tried entering `[A-Z][a-z]` in a `type="number"` yet? Know the default behavior before slapping on useless code.

Comment: @zer00ne VLAZ, it looks like OP wants to make real-time corrections to the values of the inputs if possible, native form validation can't do that.

Comment: @Teemu I don't see that stated in the question. The question just says that the value should be validated. A comment expands that a class will be added to highlight the incorrect value. That's what my demo showed - validating a value and highlighting the field if it's invalid.

Comment: @VLAZ To me it looks like "_send this value to the input_" indicates the goal ..? The question is very ambiguous, though.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers.

Here's an example using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). To recognize the 'type' of the input, a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) is used.

```js
document.addEventListener("focusout", validateField);

function validateField(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.dataset.type && origin.hasAttribute("required"))  {
    origin.classList.remove('has-error')
    const isString = origin.dataset.type === "string";
    
    const value = isString
      ? `${origin.value}`
      : parseFloat(origin.value);
      
    if (!isString && isNaN(value) || value.length < 1) {
      origin.classList.add('has-error');
    }  
    
    return value;
  }
}
```

```css
.has-error {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<label>P.V.P :</label>
<input type="number" required data-type="float" id="pvp1" name="pvp1">
<input type="text" required data-type="string" id="pvp2" name="pvp2">
```

Comment: `origin.setCustomValidity("some message")` will mark the field as invalid *and* set the message shown in the browser to "some message". Set to `null` to make it valid again. Invalid form elements can be matched by the `:invalid` pseudo-selector in CSS. The browser can do a lot of the validation part for you. In fact, all of it, if you specify `<input type="number" step="1" />` - then only whole numbers would be valid, which means no JS code is necessary to validate this, just a CSS class if you want to override the default of the browser.